# Play 2.4 and Deadbolt installation

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4, deadbolt-2

So I'm still getting to grips with Play 2.4 I wanted to use Deadbolt for authentication but it doesn't seem to be resolving any of the deadbolt classes.

In my build.sbt,

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.4.4"
)
```

In my play.plugins,

```
10000:be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltPlugin
```

In my application.conf,

```
deadbolt.java.handler=security.LoginHandler
```

The LoginHandler class,

```
package security;

import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltHandler; //does not resolve

public class LoginHandler implements DeadboltHandler {
}
```

It's not resolving any of the deadbolt packages.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not resolve"? It does not compiles when you start the application? Your IDE is not recognizing the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the documentation from http://deadbolt.ws/#/java-docs is a bit outdated.

Starting with version 2.4 Deadbolt is using dependency injection (DI) instead of the (deprecated) plugin mechanism of Play. So you don't need the `play.plugins` file anymore. Check out the [release notes](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java#240-release-notes) for Deadbolt 2.4.

I recommend to follow the Quick start guide instead: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/QuickStart.md It should get you started.

Also have a look at the Deadbolt 2 Java examples: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java-examples - they should be up to date.

Comment: I apologize for the documentation - there is a lot of stuff I need to update.  I recommend this as the basis for your work: https://leanpub.com/deadbolt-2/read

Comment: @SteveChaloner i was cursing your name and deadbolt's documentation. Then i saw your link. It's really well written, and should, perhaps, be more on display on the website?

Comment: @bharal thanks for the feedback.  I'll make it more prominent.